# Create an Outlook Quick Step for every user on a certain computer?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, automation

I need to create a quick step that shows up on every Outlook account on a certain computer.  It shouldn't be added to the user's roaming profile, although it's not terrible if that happens.  It would need to update for everyone when changed, though, so that it can be kept current.

Is there a scripting solution or way to make this happen via enterprise management tools?